# porqué no carga la foto recién subida por el usuario?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

tengo un pequeño código para que un usuario puede subir su foto de perfil o cambiarla si lo desea, el problema esta en que a la hora de cambiarla lo hace bien pero no se lo actualiza al usuario, he hecho pruebas con navegación privada para ahorrarme el cache y aun así no funciona. Para poder ver la imagen que acabo de subir tengo que cerrar el navegador y volverlo abrir, recargando la pagina no se muestra, este seria el código:

```
echo '<div class="sidebar-heading" style="color:white"><img src="../user/'.htmlspecialchars($row["Identificacion_user"]).'/'.htmlspecialchars($row["Imagen_user"]).'" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">  '.htmlspecialchars($row["Name_user"]).'
          <br>';

if ($row['Imagen_user'] != NULL){
    if (file_exists($rutaImagenes . $row['Imagen_user'])) {
        unlink($rutaImagenes . $row['Imagen_user']);
    }
}

$imagenSubida = move_uploaded_file($ruta_fichero_origen, $ruta_nuevo_destino);

if (!$imagenSubida) {
    exit('Se intentó subir la imagen, disculpe las molestias e intentelo mas tarde.');
}

$idUsuario = $row['Identificacion_user'];

$sql_img = "UPDATE usuario 
       SET Imagen_user='" . $conexion->real_escape_string($nombreDeImagen) . "' 
       WHERE Identificacion_user='" . $conexion->real_escape_string($idUsuario) . "'";
$conexion->query($sql_img);
```

He visto que presionando SHIFT+CTRL+R recarga la página y me muestra la imagen actualizada hay alguna forma de forzarle eso al usuario en php?

Comment: Necesitarás usar Ajax si quieres ver el cambio ocurrido en el servidor sin recargar la página.

Comment: No tengo conocimientos, como se haría? seria muy complicado?

Comment: Todo lo nuevo parece complicado, pero cuando aprendes cómo funciona vas sobre ruedas. Ajax es una de esas cosas que cuando lo aprendes te va a servir infinitamente en tus desarrollos. Además al ser una herramienta muy extendida encontrarás muy buenos tutoriales y varias preguntas/respuesta aquí mismo en Stackoverflow. Lo básico es muy sencillo de aprender, en uno o dos días ya podrás estar manejando Ajax sin problemas.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que php es lenguaje de servidor, es decir que hasta que no refresques la página no vas a poder ver las actualizaciones, una manera de hacerlo es como te han dicho, utilizando ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perdona si he entendido mal alguna parte del código...

La imagen nueva se llama exactamente igual que la anterior?
Si ese es el caso estás ante un problema típico de cache en el navegador.

Los navegadores (y los servidores web también para el caso) tienen una caché muy agresiva con los items estáticos (imágenes, css, js, etc...)

La forma "correcta" de solucionarlo es poner las cabeceras correctas de cache cuando se sirve la imagen...

Pero como eso no siempre es posible hay otras soluciones mas "simples". Una es que cada vez que el usuario suba una imagen esa imagen se llame distinto.

Otra es añadir un parámetro al a url `imagen.png?v=1` el cual vas incrementando cada vez que el usuario cambia su imagen.

De esa forma el navegador interpreta que la imagen no está en la cache y la vuelve a cargar.